# Can a C# method return a method?

Tags: c#, methods, lambda, return-type

Can a method in C# return a method?

A method could return a [lambda expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function) for example, but I don't know what kind of type parameter could I give to such a method, because a method isn't `Type`. Such a returned method could be assigned to some delegate.

Consider this concept as an example:

```
public <unknown type> QuadraticFunctionMaker(float a , float b , float c)
{
    return (x) => { return a * x * x  + b * x + c; };
}

delegate float Function(float x);
Function QuadraticFunction = QuadraticFunctionMaker(1f,4f,3f);
```

Comment: You already *have* declared the necessary delegate type. What exactly is your question here?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The Types you are looking for are `Action<>` or `Func<>`.

The generic parameters on both types determine the type signature of the method. If your method has no return value use `Action`. If it has a return value use `Func` whereby the last generic parameter is the return type.

For example:

```
public void DoSomething()                          // Action
public void DoSomething(int number)                // Action<int>
public void DoSomething(int number, string text)   // Action<int,string>

public int DoSomething()                           // Func<int>
public int DoSomething(float number)               // Func<float,int>
public int DoSomething(float number, string text)  // Func<float,string,int>
```

Answer (score 27):

```
public Func<float, float> QuadraticFunctionMake(float a, float b, float c) {
    return x => a * x * x + b * x + c;
}
```

The return type is `Func<float, float>`.

Answer (score 3):

`<unknown type>` = `Function`. That is,

```
public Function QuadraticFunctionMaker(float a , float b , float c)
{
    return (x) => { return a * x * x  + b * x + c; };
}
```

Is what you’re looking for since you’ve already declared the delegate `Function` to match. Alternatively, you don’t need to declare a delegate at all and can use `Func<float, Float>` as noticed by others. This is exactly equivalent. In fact, `Func<T, T>` is declared in exactly the same way as your delegate `Function` except that it’s generic.

Comment: It's better to use things like `Func<>` and `Action<>`.  I believe MS is moving away from having custom delegates all over the place.

Comment: @siride: no it's not. When you want to make your intent explicit, a strongly defined delegate is better

Comment: @JeffN825: the problem is that you can't easily pass custom delegates around in contexts that don't explicitly expect that kind of delegate.  If .NET had the ability to have delegate hierarchies or traits or something vaguely useful, I'd agree with you.  Otherwise, it's just a pain to use anything other than the generic versions.

Comment: Sure you can, as long as the signature matches. And passing around an Action<T> which takes six parameters simply named p1 through p6 is pretty confusing as to intent if you ask me.

Comment: @JeffN825: I agree, but only because the delegate system in .NET sucks.  But rather than make it suck more by having named delegates that add little and make life more complicated due to needless incompatibility between delegates having the same parameter and return types.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda expressions would take a `float` as a parameter (I believe), and then return a `float` as well. In [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework), we can represent this by the type `Func<float, float>`.

Generally, if you're dealing with lambdas that take more parameters, you can use `Func<Type1, Type2, Type3, ..., ReturnType>`, with up to eight parameters.

Answer (score -6):

You can use the `dynamic` keyword. See *[dynamic (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)*.

Comment: This is the worst possible alternative.

Comment: dynamic key, all it does is skip compile time type checking and using this keyword will be a hack rather than a solution