# How to jump to another case statement in a switch-case condition with the value of current case statement using C#

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, switch-statement

How do I jump to another case statement in a switch-case condition with the value of current case statement?

Is it possible to implement this kind of things using switch case or is there another way to implement it?

Is it possible to achieve? If not, then is there another way to achieve it?

Comment: It's not clear why you've got `goto` here. It doesn't help that there's so much context missing. Can you provide a short but *complete* example? What do you mean by "another function belonging to another case statement"? In what way does a function belong to a case?

Comment: @AnthonyRussell yes i did but it dont work. But i want any alternative if someone know

Comment: @JonSkeet If I understand correctly, he wants to hit into `case Combo` and if needed, jump into the `case Slider` based on the `if` statement.

Comment: @TyCobb exactly. I wanna jump case slider if i get "returnComboItemSelect=="Slider" but with returnComboItemSelect value. Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he is saying he wants to return a Func

Comment: @AnthonyRussell please see the edited code.I have removed the confusing part. Also please let me know if it is possible or you know any other way to achieve same thing ?

Comment: @TyCobb please see the edited code.I have removed the confusing part. Also please let me know if it is possible or you know any other way to achieve same thing ? –

Comment: @JonSkeet please see the edited code.I have removed the confusing part. Also please let me know if it is possible or you know any other way to achieve same thing ?

Answer (score 5):

This code works:

```
    switch (this.Name)
    {
    case "":
        if (this.Owner == null)
        {
            goto DoBill;
        }
        break;
    case "Bill":
    DoBill:
        break;
    }
```

However, anyone who actually does it should be shot. Or talked to very severely, at the least. Why not just do the sensible thing?

```
switch (param.Component.Type)
    {
        case "Combo":
            returnComboItemSelect = generateCB(param);
             if(returnComboItemSelect=="Slider")
             {
               returnSomething  = generateSl(param,returnComboItemSelect); //I mean no need to jump
             }
            break;                            
        case "List":
            returnSomething = generateL(param);
            break;
        case "Slider":
            returnSomething 
.....
```

Seriously, if you start jumping about between case statements then you shouldn't be using them. I'm not too keen on the code above either (duplication, but sometimes...)

Answer (score 3):

You could but a while loop around the switch statement and break out of the loop when you are done.

```
var keepLooping = true;
var switchCaseSwitch = param.Component.Type;

while(keepLooping)
{
    switch (switchCaseSwitch)
    {
        case "Combo":
            returnComboItemSelect = generateCB(param);
            if (returnComboItemSelect == "Slider")
            {
                switchCaseSwitch = "Slider";
            }
            else
            {
                keepLooping = false;
            }
            break;                            
        case "List":
            returnSomething = generateL(param);
            keepLooping = false;
            break;
        case "Slider":
            returnSomething = generateSl(param,1);
            keepLooping = false;
            break;
        case "RadioButtons":
            returnSomething = generateRB(param);
            keepLooping = false;
            break;
        case "CheckBox":
            returnSomething = generateCHB(param,flag);
            keepLooping = false;
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Unknown component type");
     }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! - 9.4 years on :-) . I'm trying to implement a semi-real-time state machine on an gasp) Arduino. I've many decades of experience in similar at the assembler level (or lower* :-) )  on older microcontrollers. I decided that a case statement inside a While loop, with each case being a state-machine case would allow me to jump hither and you between cases as desired. This is probably slightly slower in execution time than using an  "On condition yyy goto case_xxx" arrangement, but not vastly so. Your answer matches what I'd thought of - I've not seen it suggested anywhere else so far.

Comment: * or lower --> What could be lower than Assembler ? :-). In the late 1970's I did an ME using machine code using an MC6802 microprocessor. We did not have an Assembler (they cost money! :-) - so hand wrote  code on paper and hand assembled it to machine code and keyed it in on a hex keypad. It got so I could write reasonable complex "show off" programs out of my head, keyed in as I went. Using a jump table to routines at the start meant not needing to remember complex address locations. || Assembler is the most powerful language available :-) - but awesome slow to code in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a goto case.

A common use case is when you want one case to run to the next case.

```
switch ( arg )
{
    case "-file":
        if ( (i + 1) < args.Length && !args[i + 1].StartsWith("-") )
            inputBox.Text = args[++i];
        break;
    case "-language":
        _loadSelectedLanguagesAsALanguageSet = true;
        goto case "-select";
    case "-select":
        if ( (i + 1) < args.Length && !args[i + 1].StartsWith("-") )
            _loadSelectedLanguageFileOnStartup = args[++i];
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be FAR better off rethinking your architecture.

People dont tend to use GOTO in C# these days unless they are trying to break nested loops.

```
for example

foreach(var item in items){
   foreach(var name in item.people){
      if(name == WhatIAmSearchingFor)
        goto found;

   }
}
found:
   //Your Code
```

[MSDN Reference on GOTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx)

Something as simple as returning a Func, and a property bag of params is a clearer way to do this.  Or like I have in the example below just do your first param and then an enum or flag of some sort. Instead of passing an empty one just make it 0

Here is a S.O. answer on how to do this [Can a C# method return a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563470/can-method-return-method-c)

So in your example you might do this

```
public Func<ParamType,int> YourMethodName{

    YourSwitch{
       case(1)
         return YourClassName.YourMethod;
       break;
       case(2)
         return YourClassName.YourMethod2;
       break
       case(3)
         return YourClassName.YourMethod3;
       break
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could ditch the case statement and do something like that:

```
    //Setup
    var selector = new Dictionary<string, Func<Param, string, string>>();
    selector.Add("Combo", (p, flag) =>
        {
            var returnComboItemSelect = generateCB(p);
            if (returnComboItemSelect == "Slider")
            {
                return selector["Slider"](p, returnComboItemSelect);
            }
            return returnComboItemSelect;
        });
    selector.Add("List", (p, flag) => { return generateL(p); });
    selector.Add("Slider", (p, flag) => { return generateSL(p, flag); });
    selector.Add("RadioButtons", (p, flag) => { return generateRB(p); });
    selector.Add("CheckBox", (p, flag) => { return generateCHB(p, flag); });


    //use
    var result = selector[param.Component.Type](param, flag);
```